# Character encoding problem in Moodle question import

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, moodle

I created essay questions in the WebCT import format to use it in Moodle. My vim and also my file command says they are in UTF-8 encoding. Still,

> Mi az az Internet of Things, rövidítve IoT ?

becomes

> Mi az az Internet of Things, rÃ¶vidÃ­tve IoT ?

when I import the file into Moodle.

To my knowledge, Moodle uses and expects UTF-8 text. What is the problem then and how can I fix this?

UPDATE: I tried it with iso-8859-2 (Central European) import file but ő and ű was displayed as if I written it with iso-8859-1 (Western Europe).

Interestingly, when I copy a hand-written question from Moodle, vim says it is in UTF-8. So it seems that Moodle use other encodings at import than it uses on the surface. Also it does not differentiate iso-latin-1 and iso-latin-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting "Mojibake" because "latin1" is incorrectly being used (or defaulted).  See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Answer (score 0):

Is this with MySql?

It might be the database coding.

There is a list of settings here for MySql

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/MySQL_full_unicode_support